# C Program to check if string is Palindrome or not

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, palindrome

i have some struggles with my C program!
It should check wether a string is a palindrome or not! it should not pay attention to non-alphabetic characters, so the program should recognize this as a palindrome!
"He lived as a devil, eh?"
That's what i got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[39];
    int left = 0;
    int right = 40;

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    fgets(sentence, 40, stdin);

    while(1) {

        while(left < right && !(isalpha(sentence[left])))
            left++;
        while(right > left && !(isalpha(sentence[right])))
            right--;

        if(left >= right)
            break;

        else {

            if(sentence[left] != sentence[right]) {
                printf("Not a Palindrome");
                return 0;
            }

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    printf("Palindrome");

    return 0;
}
```

It's always printing: NOT A PALINDROME!
Even if it is one.

Comment: Did you try even basic printf debugging ? Did you consider that `fgets` leaves a `\n` at the end of the string ?

Comment: `sentence[right]` is not valid when `right == 40` which was the initial value.

Comment: You should convert the chararacters to lower or uppercase. `H != h`.

Comment: If you have `char sentence[39]` there are 39 characters in it. Not 40. Not 38. `fgets(sentence, 40, stdin);` will fill up to 40 characters. You only have 39. The last index in `sentence` is 38. Not 39 and not 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few changes to your program. Firstly not breaking the array indexing, next using the string length instead of accessing undefined values, third checking same case letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[200];                             // provide plenty of room
    int left = 0;
    int right;                                      // do not assume the length

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin);        // limit the input
    right = strlen(sentence);                       // now get the length

    while(1) {
        while(left < right && !(isalpha(sentence[left])))
            left++;
        while(right > left && !(isalpha(sentence[right])))
            right--;
        if(left >= right)
            break;
        else {
            if(toupper(sentence[left]) != toupper(sentence[right])) {  // get case the same
                printf("Not a Palindrome\n");
                return 0;
            }
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    printf("Palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program sessions:

```
Enter a message: He lived as a devil, eh?
Palindrome

Enter a message: palindrome
Not a Palindrome
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a separate function that checks whether the inputted sentence is a palindrome.

As for your code then these statements

```
char sentence[39];
int left = 0;
int right = 40;

printf("Enter a message: ");
fgets(sentence, 40, stdin);
```

lead to undefined behavior because the array sentence has only 39 elements while you are trying to enter 40 characters. Also the entered string can have kess than 40 characters. You need to determine the length of the string.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how a corresponding function can be written.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int is_palindrome(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s);

    const char *first = s, *last = s + n;

    if (n)
    {

        do
        {
            while ( *first && !isalpha((unsigned char)*first)) ++first;
            if (first != last)
            {
                while (!isalpha((unsigned char)*--last));
            }
        } while ( toupper( ( unsigned char )*first ) == 
                  toupper( ( unsigned char )*last ) && 
                  first != last && 
                  ++first != last);
    }

    return first == last;
}

#define N   100

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        char s[N];

        printf("Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): ");

        if (!fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) || s[0] == '\n') break;

        printf("\nThe sentence is%s palindrome.\n\n",
            is_palindrome(s) ? "" : " not");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a sentence (Enter - exit): He lived as a devil, eh

The sentence is palindrome.

Enter a sentence (Enter - exit):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the right as the end of the string:

```
#include <string.h>

// ...

    right = strlen(sentence) - 1;
```

Comment: True, but it already might crash a bit earlier while reading `sentence` as it can only hold 39 bytes but it is filled using `fgets(sentence, 40, stdin);`

Comment: That's correct. He should resize the sentence or update the fgets.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code format

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char data[100] = "ABCDEDCBA";
    length = strlen(data);
    printf("length is %d\n", length);

    while (i < length)
    {
        if (data[i] != data[length - i - 1])
        {
            count = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        printf(" not palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("palindrome");
    }

    return 0;
}
```